# Azure Functions deployment failing when using scm-do-build-during-deployment: true

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Functions Linux app using Github Actions. I've used the Deployment Center in the Azure Portal to connect my Github to enable CICD. Now that goes fine, but I want to use Playwright in my Azure Function, so I need to enable scm-do-build-during-deployment: true. I've added this setting to my workflow yaml, but then the deployment doesn't work anymore. I also added some other settings, which I came across when I searched the interwebs. Now this is the yaml I have:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/azure/functions-action
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js project to Azure Function App - app-name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: "." # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: "16.x" # set this to the node version to use (supports 8.x, 10.x, 12.x)

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout GitHub Action"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: "Resolve Project Dependencies Using Npm"
        shell: bash
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
          popd

      - name: "Run Azure Functions Action"
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          app-name: "app-name"
          slot-name: "Production"
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_A5413AC6097F4B21B4A709C270747826 }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          respect-funcignore: true
```

I also added the setting to my application settings in Azure, but to no avail. Furthermore, I added this setting: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0 to the app settings.

Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

- In the YAML the `uses` tag is not aligned with the name and the other tags

```
- name: "Run Azure Functions Action"
  uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
  id: fa
```

- Add `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH` in app settings with its value set to zero.

Rest remains the same and I was able to deploy the function.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @MohitGanorkar, thanks for your answer. Can you share your deployment yaml with me? I processed your suggestions in my yaml but it still doesn't work.